# Tilestache issue serving crossed polygons

Tags: tilestache

Tilestache doesn't serve polygons that are self crossed. like in the picture below.

[image]

I checked whether or not the polygon is stored within my postgresql, and it was the case. Therefore, the problem comes in serving, I kind of think that tilestache is not able to treat self crossed polygons. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because a [self crossing polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31109/why-are-self-intersecting-polygons-bad) is invalid in the [OGC simple feature](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) model. I can't think of a single program that will correctly display them.

Comment: There are many programs & librares that renders this kind of polygones: QGis, ArcGis, Leaflet ...

Comment: they will display them, but not **correctly** it is always best to fix this sort of error